# Hi Fi quality Bluetooth player

Tags: stereo, home

I have a high-end hi-fi system (monitor audio studio 20se speakers, talk electronics preamplifier and 4 separate power amplifiers) and am wondering if there is a piece of kit available that will play music via Bluetooth (in a similar way to modern cars). It would have to connect to the preamplifier via coaxial cables. Does anyone have any recommendations? Budget around the £1,000 mark.

Apologies if this question is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The best available bluetooth technology currently available is bluetooth 4.0. As I presume you are already aware, Bluetooth technology is designed with data transfer at its heart and might not cater to audiophile requirements, such as higher sample rates.

I've found a small receiver that might meet your requirements, perhaps if only as an interim solution:

[Belkin HD Bluetooth Music Receiver](http://www.dabs.com/products/belkin-hd-bluetooth-music-receiver---with-nfc-8TGR.html?prev=8P9C)
I am aware of *BOSE* and their intentions of bringing out a new amplifier that will support WIFI connections, however, they usually only work with *BOSE* systems and the projected release date for this isn't till spring 2014..